# Tomcat server freezing when generate report several times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm using jasper reports to generate reports in my web applications. The application is a billing system. So it should be generated reports (bills) frequently. But the problem is the application is not responding after generating the bill several times. I have to restart the application from tomcat applications list. What should I do to fix this. I use following code to generate the bill.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{orderId}/bill/customer")
public void generateCustomerBill(@PathVariable("orderId") Long orderId, HttpServletResponse response) {

        //parameters
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("paraOrderId", orderId);        
        params.put("paraPaidAmount", 0.0);

        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            DataSource dataSource = config.getDataSource();

            //load report file
            String inputStream = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/customer_bil_tal.jasper");

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, params, dataSource.getConnection());

            HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(response.getWriter()));
            exporter.exportReport();

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerBillController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerBillController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerBillController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your method has exit, it may lock on some resources.